# Von Neumann Neighborhood

Tags: code-golf, cellular-automata

Your goal is to make a function that takes the coordinates of a cell in 2D space and a distance \$r\$ and returns the coordinates of all cells in the  input coordinate's von Neumann neighborhood of radius \$r\$. That is, all cells at most \$r\$ away in [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).
For example, given the following cell coordinates and radius pairs:

```
[1, 1], 1 -> [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]  
[2, 2], 2 -> [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 2]
```

This is what the von Neumann neighborhood looks like:

[image: Neighborhood]

More information about the von Neumann neighborhood can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest amount of bytes wins!

Comment: Do we have to handle input `r = 0`?

Comment: Both the Wikipedia article and the images suggest the input cell should be included in the Von Neumann neighboorhood. Can we do this as well?

Comment: More test cases would be nice.

Comment: Does the order of points matter?

Comment: @LuisMendo no, you don't

Comment: @Adám the order of points do not matter

Comment: Voting "Leave Open" for now as I believe the question is answerable in its current state. While there are some things that would be nice to have clarified, it seems easy enough to determine the author's intent for most.

Comment: I think the output should include the input cell because the wikipedia article and the images (as ovs points out) as well as the description ("at most `r` away", and a cell is 0 units away from itself, which is at most `r`) all point towards that.

Comment: @someone Edited you post to try to get it reopened. Have included the input cell in the output. Please feel free to revert or change my edit for whatever reasons.

Comment: Can the output have repetitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
k□0zJẋΠṠUMṠ
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJr4pahMHpK4bqLzqDhuaBVTeG5oCIsIiIsIjJcblsyLCAyXSJd) Takes \$r\$ then the coordinate.

```
k□          # cardinal directions [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0]]
  0z        # 0 zipped into self  [[0,0]]
    J       # join                [[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1],[-1,0],[0,0]]
     ẋ      # repeated into a list r times
      Π     # reduce by cartesian product
       Ṡ    # vectorising sum
        U   # remove duplicates
         M  # pair each direction into the input coordinate
          Ṡ # and sum to it
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 23 bytes

-4 thanks to ovs.

Anonymous tacit infix function, taking coordinates of a cell and radius as left and right arguments. Requires 0-based indexing.

```apl
{⍺∘+¨⍵-⍸⍵≥+/¨|∘.,⍨⍵…-⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9e561DFD@9CKR71bdR/17gBSjzqXausfWlEDFNfTedQLknnUsAwoubX2fxpQ16PevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtolA84KDnIFkiIdn8H9DBUOFNAVDLiMFIyBtBAA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; left argument is `⍺` and right argument is `⍵`:

`⍵…-⍵` inclusive integer range from radius to negative radius

`∘.,⍨` Cartesian selfie product

`⊢m←` assign to `m` and pass that

`|` absolute values

`+/¨` sum each (gives matrix of Manhattan distances)

`⍵≥` indicate which ones are less than or equal to the radius

`⍸` **ɩ**ndices where true

`⍵-` subtract from radius

`⍺∘+¨` add the cell coordinates to each

Comment: `m[⍸...]` is the same as `⍵-⍸...` (in a different order) with index origin `0`:  https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR765HHTO0D6141LtV91HvDiCl8ahz6aOersPTNbX1D62oAUrr6TzqBSl41LAMqGZr7f@0R20THvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv8H0p7@QHUGXIYKhgppCoZcRgpGYNpAwQBIGwEA

Comment: @ovs Thanks. That's clever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 64 bytes

```perl
sub n($x,$y,$d){map{//;map[$x+$',$y+$_],-$d+abs..$d-abs}-$d..$d}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwFET3niLIhybkt1XBlZtewJXLEkpLq0Q0CUkKlZCrG9PKLN7MwIyZ7OuckpsHoigsCB@EkYV3b0JdXzJaWDgUuefQCSxh5P3gqgrGMjPmvPq4HXh985Y2loWnlooUWCDJDyTsW4CuPQhccRRiH0lj485YqTz9rxQ9YRZjLH218VIrl8rrfer9bCfu5ENtzv0A)

Saved 4 bytes, thanks to Xcali.

Comment: You can cut 2 bytes by eliminating `$i`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCsIgGIXvewoZP0yZ2yroqpu9QFddDhkbWhilog4W4qtnbsW5@D44nGOEfZ5ScvOEFIaFwpsCJ@E1mtC25xU9LBWUuahgYBGPkyM18KYBXmePf4/bhddXb3FnSXhoqVBJS4ryBwpFDzD0e0ZXHBgrIups3Bkrlce/lcJHmkMISR9tvNTKpfpyE6OfraicvKvN3Bc "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Cut a couple more bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwFET3niLIhybkt1XBlZtewJXLEkpLq0Q0CUkKlZCrG9PKLN7MwIyZ7OuckpsHoigsCB@EkYV3b0JdXzJaWDgUuefQCSxh5P3gqgrGMjPmvPq4HXh985Y2loWnlooUWCDJDyTsW4CuPQhccRRiH0lj485YqTz9rxQ9YRZjLH218VIrl8rrfer9bCfu5ENtzv0A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

-1 thanks to ovs

```
D(ŸãʒÄO¹s@}€+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//0QoxbjDo8qSw4RPwrlzQH3igqwr//8yClsyLCAyXQ)

Takes input as range, coordinates

Explanation:

```
D duplicate the range in the stack
( negate
Ÿ push the range [-range..range]
ã Cartesian power
 ʒ filter
  Ä absolute value, vectorizes over each of the coordinates
   O sum - distance from 0,0
    ¹s@ less than or equals to the range
 } end filter
€ map
+ add, with the implicit center coordinate
```

Comment: `D(Ÿ` saves a byte

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒRṗ2AS>³ƲÐḟ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//xZJS4bmXMkFTPsKzxrLDkOG4nyv///8y/1syLDJd)

A dyadic link that accepts the radius and the point.

### Explanation

```
ŒRṗ2AS>³ƲÐḟ+   Main dyadic link accepting r, [x,y]
ŒR             [-r..r]
  ṗ2           [-r..r]^2 (Cartesian product)
         Ðḟ    Filter out by
        Ʋ      (
    A            Absolute value (of both)
     S           Sum
      >³         Greater than r
        Ʋ      )
           +   Add [x,y] to each
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ŒRAạ³ŒR;€Ʋ€Ẏ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCDHh7sWHtoMZFg/alpzbBOQeLirT/v///9G/6ONdIxiAQ)

A dyadic link that accepts the radius and the point.

### Explanation

```
ŒRAạ³ŒR;€Ʋ€Ẏ+   Main dyadic link accepting r, [x,y]
ŒR              [-r..r]
          €     For each i in [-r..r]
         Ʋ      (
  A               |i|
   ạ³             |(|i| - r)|
     ŒR           [-|(|i| - r)| .. |(|i| - r)|]
       ;€         Join each with i
         Ʋ      )
           Ẏ    Tighten (flatten by one level)
            +   Add [x,y] to each
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(c,r)(d=t(expand.grid(c[1]+-r:r,c[2]+-r:r)))[,colSums(abs(d-c))<=r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7CoUwEAB7T5FyF1chKeXlFJbBQjcqgm@V9YO3jwSLgWGK0XSL@DRdwueyCTApQvQnjM/eS6xnXSJwsF1ZaaPEwX2GiIF4W9vrf0A/HBArRvx57fIQGCwZixlTfMGRcZgxRXoB)

**How?  Un-golfed code**

```r
vnn=function(c,r)                       # c = (x,y) coordinates; r = radius
d=expand.grid(c[1]+(-r:r),c[2]+(-r:r))) # d = all combinations of coordinates from x-r to x+r, y-r to y+r
d=t(d)                                  # transpose d so that (x,y) coordinates are rows instead of columns
d[,colSums(abs(d-c))<=r]                # select the columns for which the sum of absolute differences to
                                        # the given (x,y) are less than or equal to r
                                        # (note that R recycles c to subtract it from every pair of elements
                                        # by row in d, so 'd-c' produces all the differences in x,y coordinates)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
oo+#&/@DiamondMatrix@#~Position~1-#-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P//9pIX52spq@g4umYm5@XkpvoklRZkVDsp1AfnFmSWZ@Xl1hrrKuoZq/wOKMvNKoquVlWt17dKilWOjlY1iY9UcHByquaqrDXUMa0EIxjSu5ar9DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

```hs
(a,b)!r=[(a+k,b+j)|k<-[-r..r],j<-[abs k-r..r-abs k]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNRJ0lTscg2WiNRO1snSTtLsybbRjdat0hPryhWJwvITEwqVsgG83XBzNjY/7mJmXm2BUWZeSUqGoYGOoYGBpqKRv8B)

I'm sure someone will figure out a more clever way to do this that isn't nearly so long.  But for now I am stumped.

Comment: You can get rid of 1 byte by taking the x and y-coordinates as seperate values instead of a tuple: https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNRMUmzyDZaI1E7WydJO0uzJttGN1q3SE@vKFYnC8hMTCpWyAbzdcHM2Nj/uYmZebYFRZl5JSoahgaKhgYGmkb/AQ

Comment: @ovs I'd really don't like taking input and producing output in different manners.  I'd prefer to keep it tuple in tuples out, even if a more unconventional/esoteric format saves a byte.

Comment: This one is a little byte shorter: https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNRJ0lTscg2WiNRO1snSTtLsybbRjdVoUgnC0ipFOkmJhUrZMdypSpU2EbrVujpVcT@z03MzLMtKMrMK1HRMDTQMTQw0FQ0@g8A

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 28 bytes

```
+"1](]#~(>:1#.|))>@,@{@;~@i:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tZUMYzViles07KwMlfVqNDXtHHQcqh2s6xwyrf5rcqUmZ@QrGAJhmoIhhKOuDqGNgDBNweg/AA)

- `+"1...` Add the left argument (the center point) to each element of the right argument (the width) after transforming the right argument by `...`
- `i:` The first part of that transformation is the "both direction" integers of the width.  Eg, `i: 2` produces `_2 _1 0 1 2`.
- `>@,@{@;~@` Take the Cartesian product of that bi-directional integer list with itself `{@;~`, flatten the result `,` and unbox `>@`.
- `](]#~...)` Now filter that Cartesian product result by the following...
- `(>:1#.|)` For each point on the list, is the sum `1#.` of the absolute values `|` of the `x` and `y` coordinates greater than or equal to `>:` the  original right arg (the width)?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 81 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,d:[(x+i,y+j)for i in range(-d,d+1)for j in range(abs(i)-d,d+1-abs(i))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYm7DoAgDAB/hbENdVA3E79EHTD4KNFqkEG@Ho0M5qa7O2NYD6mTtH3azD5ao26KZJsObs0UtcP58IoVi/JGlgkKS1aXX3V/NeMFjPkVWXBIp2cJcAUPAhW9IGJ6AA)

Three bytes saved, thanks to ovs.

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the first `lambda` and you don't need to count the `n=`: [81 bytes, Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYm7DoAgDAB/hbENdVA3E79EHTD4KNFqkEG@Ho0M5qa7O2NYD6mTtH3azD5ao26KZJsObs0UtcP58IoVi/JGlgkKS1aXX3V/NeMFjPkVWXBIp2cJcAUPAhW9IGJ6AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,r:{s}|{(a+x,b+d-x)for d in(1,-1)*r for a,b in f(s,r-1)for x in(0,d)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvBDoMgEATQe79ijrt1TQRvJv0YCCEladGgBxr12yl7nDcz2@94r3luLb4@7uuDwy5lOff7OskNVfwQxspxLQhImYyMhp8FCk58J0Tqj65KVTeTBL6bxqT9JDACK5iXB7CVlA@KRFYsCxJz@wM)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 61 bytes

```scala
(x,y,r)=>for(a<- -r to r;d=r-a.abs;b<-y-d to y+d)yield(x+a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vYOsqmTqQHqJFRn7DB4Gjg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 146 bytes

```java
int[][]f(int x,int y,int d){int i=~d,r[][]=new int[1-2*d*i][],p=0,a,j;for(;i++<d;)for(j=a=i<0?d+i:d-i;j>~a;)r[p++]=new int[]{x+i,y+j--};return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU9Na8MwDL33V4hCwa6dkPZYN90v2KlH44NXp0POJ47TNYT0r2d26JgEkpCenp6sfujEmnK5Vbrv4VNjMy3YeKmkupNQwJPHOK7R0CkmzF@GuwjJm@IHIvyQHPdmj6HFuzzjmltxbx0RyNjZCBprm@scz9mHYXgyCQp7eWlBnewY@@dR05MhH5lNklm4wg@uASfmBaAbviq8Qe@1D@nRooE6qCVX77D5lgo0nTYQ7K0eXNEPlYccInd8jND0To48OBUrMqgCssKhhNN7ga4jgOvY@6JO28GnXbjgq79TaVirtSdbuTMcdkZteSkzxaGUB0VX6nkzL78)

minus 6 bytes, thanks to ceilingcat

minus 2 bytes, thanks to ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 82 bytes

```powershell
$x,$y,$r=$args;-$r..$r|%{$i=$_;($d=($i-replace'-')-$r)..-$d|%{,(($x+$i),($y+$_))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHRboIwFH3nK5rmbraxEAXfTBMSk71umb4RQxC7DYPAWsg0yLezUovuYVv7cLg9p@cebqvyS0j1IfK8h7emSOusLLiD9Gp7ODE4M5AcEvmuli5IzwN5eWgh4xAvCew5gcyVosqTVEzcCdUS6nku7LWIEQKnKWSUEThPIaa06/rBuHOgFqpeJUooxFFITLuwNTCsrKiaevgYSJ/pTW@cOFUircXecDiaMeRvGYrmDM0tjnUwoM/QzOLcom9x5BcDBpYPLB9YfjHU@Nq@Y39lnDO9/8s4Zpv9ltVkG3s41IGNno7iIaE/BqUHagRgGjMYe@iH8OxR7I2HV6UUqslrHQIDIeTx9rwoNBeotsQREIjdQ5kVmCFMt7ij9wpffVSTpkIpjq0jdsUnvgWwIpN5yqOX9apRdXl83h00vQ3btb092ixfjcndrXM6@8uXp1Iek9rdJLtc9N8)

Comment: nice `abs`! ◕‿◕

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,r:{s}|{(a+x//3,b-1+x%3)for x in(-2,4,0,2)*r for a,b in f(s,r-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsMgEAXQfU/xN4WZZiRRuwr0MEqRCq0JJgtLmrNb3T5463d/LcnWGh5v9/FPh03yfGzn7yA3lHG04pUeytVyWDIKYiJl5C6TGL5ldHTiGyNQq0rzWTvGTpNAC4zAYr4Aa45pp0BkWhZE5voH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```scala
(x,y,r)=>for(a<- -r to r;d=a.abs-r;b<-d to-d)yield(x+a,y+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcixCsIwFEbhvU/xj7k0cXC0TcHRwclRHG6aBColbdMgDeKzRx0UDmf41p5HLpO5uz7hzEOA25ILdsVxnp/Vg0f4A8QpJInfCLrDxS3XP9MNuohNZhlJd36KglsFFZEmxMZq3rFZVWxMq@zHlKU8uNGKrWaZa0NljkNIwou9xDei6lXe)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 75 bytes

```javascript
p=>n=>{for(i=-n;i<=n;++i)for(j=k=n-(i*i)**.5;j>=-k;)print(p[0]+i,p[1]+j--)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchRCsMgDADQ6yTalE0YDGy8iPhRBkIspMGW/pSd3bH3@dp6rceni510vUflYZyU0133DsKkURbW6L3gfxpvrATiBJ2bX7Elpi2iddETLD@Kl8nys/hGhN9RIYcpFISA4wc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 38 bytes

```
AQf!>+ahThGaeTeGH*r-hGHh+hGHr-eGHh+eGH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zEwTdFOOzEjJMM9MTUk1d1Dq0g3w90jQxtIFOmmglhA4v//aCMdo1gdIwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 58 bytes

```julia
(x,y,d)->[(x+i,y+j) for i=-d:d,j=-d:d if abs(i)+abs(j)<=d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy7CoAwDAB3vyJjQiOoOIn1R8RBiYUUqeID6tfXx3TDHeevRccyJmcTRr5ZKO96jEb5Np7ArTuozaUR9j9AHYzTgUrmg6fWypC@7FUBiqbOALZdw7kEdFhx9S4pm4OkBw)